# what does this # mean in function parameter in C++

Tags: c++

```
template<typename Mutex>
class CMutexLock
{

public:
    CMutexLock(Mutex& mutexIn, const char* pszName, const char* pszFile, int nLine, bool fTry = false) : lock(mutexIn, boost::defer_lock)
    {
        if (fTry)
            TryEnter(pszName, pszFile, nLine);
        else
            Enter(pszName, pszFile, nLine);
    }
};

typedef CMutexLock<CCriticalSection> CCriticalBlock;    
#define LOCK(cs) CCriticalBlock criticalblock(cs, #cs, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

I'm learning open source code and wonder, what does # in `#cs` means and if possible what does it do in that code?
It is used in `#define LOCK(cs) CCriticalBlock criticalblock(cs, #cs, __FILE__, __LINE__)` it is defining `LOCK(cs)` from CMutexLock template for constructing CMutexLock class, It is on second parameter which on the CMutexClass constructor is receiving pointer to null terminated string

Comment: You really need to find the `CCriticalBlock` template and the `criticalblock` 'constructor' or function (or macro) that's associated with it.  And then you should probably show an example were LOCK is used — or, at least, finding such an example would help you understand its use.

Comment: thanks for the advice sir x)

Comment: See this [manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) page.

Comment: thanks for the manual, sorry didnt search enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `#define` macro, `#` before a symbol means to "stringify" the symbol, meaning that the symbol that proceeds it becomes quoted.

So for example given this macro:

```
#define STR(x) #x
```

Used like this:

```
char *p = STR(hello);
```

Gets replaced with:

```
char *p = "hello";
```